# SSH into Windows 10 Bash only gets into DOS shell not Bash

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to ssh into windows 10 bash on my local machine.

When I do
`ssh localhost` I am prompted for my windows password and can then ssh into a DOS shell.  How do I access bash from there?

The same occurs when I try to ssh from a cygwin terminal on another laptop on my home network. I am able to ssh into linux machines fine (from windows 10 bash)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you enable Developer Mode you can see 2 new services are loaded on startup, SSHBroker and SSHProxy and they are bound to port 22. You can try disabling them and you should can do `ssh localhost` again.